# Android: onCLickListener for Custom View

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have created an Custom View that should change his appearence on Click.
The `onClickListener` and the `OnTouchEventListener` get called correctly and the 
appreance changed in the View.

But as soon as I set another `onClickListener` at the Activity to interact with 
other Methods, only the `onClickListener` from the Activity gets called and the 
one inside the View got ignored.

Is there any possibility to inherit the `onClickListener` from the View to the 
Activity so that both (Visualchange and call of a Method) OnClick's get called?

I've also tried to implement the View with Drawables and a `StateListDrawable`, but also without any luck since "state_pressed" won't get called.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the OnClickListener from outside of the view, for instance doing: `customView.setOnClickListener(listener)`, you can do this:

1. Inside your custom view declare a variable of type `onClickListener`:

```
private OnClickListener onClickListener;
```

2. Override this two methods that way:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP &&
            (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
        if(onClickListener != null) onClickListener.onClick(this);
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        setPressed(true);
    }
    else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if(onClickListener != null) onClickListener.onClick(this);
        setPressed(false);
    }
    else {
        setPressed(false);
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

3. And override the `setOnClickListener` setting your variable:

```
@Override
public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
    onClickListener = l;
}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to set listener in custom view, **you must set the listener in the constructor of the custom view**. Otherwise it will not be called outside. (You shouldn't use function that will handle the clicks)

Answer (score -1):

You are overriding the OnClickListener of the object when you set it from the Activity. if you do something like this in your onClick() method from the Activity it should work.

```
public void onClick(View v){
    //Do whatever you want
    super.onClick(v);
}
```

However you probably should not be setting your button graphic from the click or touch listeners. That is precisely what button selectors are for.